# oracle reader returning System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand as value

Tags: oracle, datareader, getstring

i'm stumped by this thing.

i'm using the very simple following code:

```
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=myservice)));User Id=myuser;Password=mypassword";
            con.Open();
            OracleCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT SRVID FROM mytable WHERE USED=0 AND ROWNUM = 1";
            OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                readercheck = reader.GetString(0);
            }
```

For whatever reason, reader.GetString(0) won't work because the value it's trying to access is an object of type System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.

If I use reader.ToString() it ACTUALY RETURNS "System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand" as a string!

help would be appreciated!!

Comment: I'm not sure if you're making assumptions. `reader.toString()` returning that isn't odd. It isn't clear why you think that is causing you a problem; you said it 'won't work because' of that, but I don't see the link. It would help if you showed what actual error you're getting, as 'won't work' isn't very descriptive. How is `readerCheck` declared?

Comment: you're right, I do understand now why reader.toString() would be expected to return that, but the problem remains :)

I'm off-site now but will check for the exact error tomorrow.

readerCheck is declared as a public string at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Hi Alex - I just checked, Error i sof type "Specified cast is not valid", with the source being System.Data.OracleClient.

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from the code you've shown, not earlier? Showing the whole error stack and how the line numbers in the error(s) correspond to your source code might help.

Comment: The problem was resolved!

The data I was trying to pull was of raw16 type and so couldn't fit the string parameter I was trying to feed it into.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found this while searching for a solution to the same problem. GetString(0) won't work because you'll get an illegal cast error, probably because the first element in the reader is a decimal, which won't cast directly to a string.

```
  reader.item(1).tostring
```

or

```
  reader.GetString(1)
```